# SVG: Moving mouse to <image> element triggers mouseout event of parent <g> element (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, d3.js

I have `<g>` element with `<rect>` and `<image>` inside. `<g>` has mouseout event listener. The problem is that when I move mouse from rect to image (within the same `g`), the mouseout event is triggered (followed by 'mouseover').

Here's example. (and [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw8GY/))

```
var x = 120;

var g = d3.select("svg")
    .append("g")
    .on('mouseover', function() {
        d3.select(this).append("text").text("mouseover").attr('transform','translate(0,'+x+')');
        x+=20;
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
        d3.select(this).append("text").text("mouseout").attr('transform','translate(0,'+x+')');  
        x+=20;  
    })

g.append("rect")
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .style('fill', 'lightgreen')

g.append('image')
    .attr("width", 30)
    .attr("height", 30)
    .attr("x", 35)
    .attr("y", 35)
    .attr("xlink:href","https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f70adb32032d39add2559c2609a90d03?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG")
```

How to prevent the mouseout event from triggering?

Comment: tried hover? gives the same effect?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918194/d3-js-mouseover-event-not-working-properly-on-svg-group) might help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use mouseout and mouseover on a parent container, you get events when the mouse moves between descendant elements. If you only want to hear where the mouse enters or leaves the parent, use [**mouseenter** and **mouseleave**](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5247027/730dc17e34b04034bddd881f03d8b99ee1d31e0d) instead.

Comment: Thank you!
BTW, mouseenter and mouseleave didn't work in 3.0.6. Needed to update to latest version of d3.js (3.2.7 for the time being)

Comment: The mouseenter and mouseleave polyfills were added in 3.1. See the [release notes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/releases) for the full history.

Answer (score -2):

Using

**onpointerleave**

solved problem.