# How to make Plotly.js listen the click events of the tick labels?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, charts, plotly

[image]

So, in this dynamic chart, I want to change the Y-axis' min and max values when any of the Y-axis' Tick Label is clicked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add a d3 event listener to all y-ticks and make sure that the SVG group gets all the [events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16923563/2776376).
Wrapping the whole snippet in Plotly's `afterplot` event makes sure that the event listener does not get lost after updating the graph.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4], 
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17], 
  type: 'scatter'
};
var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4], 
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9], 
  type: 'scatter'
};
var data = [trace1, trace2];
var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv');
Plotly.newPlot(myPlot, data);
myPlot.on('plotly_afterplot', function(){
    Plotly.d3.selectAll(".yaxislayer-above").selectAll('text')
          .on("click", function(d) {
            alert("Hello, I am " + d.x);
          });
});
```

```css
.yaxislayer-above {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Btw after zooming in, it doesn't listen to any click events. And, there's nothing mentioned on the Plotly.js Full Reference about this issue.

Comment: Good catch! The answer was modified accordingly

Comment: I am completely new to d3.js, that's why I couldn't figure out. Anyway thanks a ton!

Comment: I think some behavior changed in plotly 2.x since you need to use d3 by itself now AND `d.x` is not the right number any more

Comment: Try with cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.2.0.min.js

Comment: I found the original value is accessible through `d.target.__data__.x` but I don't know d3 at all so I there might be an easier way of getting this value